How to access and set a parameter into a a transition in an AnimationTree?
I'm trying to access and set the xfade_time parameter in an specific function with different value, but I can't find the way to do it. I found a method that requires the ID of the transition but there is no method to get it. There is another method called AnimationTree.set_xfade_time() but it returns null or I'm using it wrong... Thats far away from my knowledge right now so any help will be really appreciated!
